# What is the name of this combination of screw and rotating metal piece that locks it?

Tags: screws, furniture, wooden-furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I recently self assembled a wooden furniture and had to use these parts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

They are used to connect boards at 90 degrees to each other. The screw is screwed into one board and the lock is embedded in the other board. The head of the screw goes in a hole and into the lock area which is then rotated to hold it in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be the cam lock nut and cam screw fastener.

They are commonly found in DIY assembly products sold by various retailers including IKEA.  According to a recent post I've read IKEA may be looking to replace this fastener type in its products, but I haven't seen any changes yet so probably best not to hold your breath.  However, there are alternatives to this fastener such as [TorpedoCSIS](http://www.engineering.com/AdvancedManufacturing/ArticleID/11459/Better-Connectors-The-Future-of-Flatpack-Furniture.aspx).